# model.build() stopped working after upgrading to sequelizejs 6

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have a node app I developer using node.js and sequelize (version 4.28). Recently, I did a "npm audit fix" command and it upgraded my sequelize to version 6.0.0. Now my app breaks because apparently the Model.build method has either been removed or renamed (even though it still appears in the official docs).

I define my models like this:

```
module.exports =(sequelize,DataTypes) =>
{
return sequelize.define('CardType',{
    TypeID: {type: DataTypes.BIGINT, allowNull:false,primaryKey:true, autoIncrement:true},
    description: {type: DataTypes.STRING(75), unique:true}
});
```

}

I then import them into my app like this:

```
const sqlCon = new Sequelize(keys.dbName,keys.dbUser, keys.dbPassword,
{dialect:'postgresql',
 host:keys.dbHost,
 pool:20,
 logging:false
});
const CardType =sqlCon.import('../models/CardType');
```

This all works, the problem starts when I try to create a new model like this:

```
var cardType1 = CardType.build({description:'My Type Card'});
        await cardType1.save();
```

This fails with this error message:

```
TypeError: CardType.build is not a function
```

Can someone please tell me what I need to do to fix this? I can downgrade back to squelize 4, but I would like to be on the latest version to prevent security issues in my code. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: There is no version 6 of sequelize: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/releases

Comment: Actually, my both my package.json and package-lock.json say version 6.0.0. In the package-lock.json, it says : "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/sequelize/-/sequelize-6.0.0.tgz". I just checked, and it is a valid url. How come?

Comment: It looks like they did cut a release and push to npm, but it was supposed to be a `-alpha`. It's not good that it's in npm as just 6.0.0. Looks like there is a 7.0.0 too. You should definitely be switching back to some v5 release though. Latest is 5.18.4

Comment: I will try switching to 5.18 and see how it works. I suppose it was too much to expect npm audit fix to do things correctly. From now on, I will manually upgrade my packages.